# Href does not work

Tags: html, href

Hoping someone can help me with this. The following menu items below (Get on Amazon etc) change the information on the page within the browser, but the first menu should change the actual page to my index page. For some reason I cannot get it to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]--  >
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <title>Painful Words Dot Com</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
<!--
```

Painful Words
    -->

```
    <!-- Google Web Font Embed -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,500,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/painful_main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a rel="nofollow" href="http://browsehappy.com">upgrade your raasclaat browser</a> or <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 affix text-center" style="z-index: 1;">
            <h1 class="painful-site-title">
                    <a href="#">Painful Words</a>
                    <img src="images/btn-menu.png" alt="main menu" id="m-btn" class="pull-right visible-xs visible-sm" >
            </h1>

            <ul id="responsive" style="display:none" class="hidden-lg hidden-md"></ul><!-- /.responsive -->
        </div>

        <div class="menu visible-md visible-lg">
            <ul id="menu-list">
                <li class="active back-menu"><a href="http://www.painfulwords.com">Go Back</a></li>
                <li class="inactive purchase-menu"><a href="#purchase">Purchase</a></li>
                <li class="amazon-menu"><a href="#amazon">Get on Amazon</a></li>
                <li class="google-menu"><a href="#google">Get on Google Play</a></li>
                <li class="noble-menu"><a href="#noble">Get on Barnes & Noble</a></li>








            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.menu -->

        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="images/gone.jpg" id="purchase-img" class="main-img inactive" alt="purchase">
                <img src="images/love.jpe" id="amazon-img" class="inactive" alt="amazon">
                <img src="images/fam.jpe" id="google-img" class="inactive" alt="google">
                <img src="images/fam2.jpe" id="noble-img"  class="inactive" alt="noble">
```

Comment: Which "first menu"? `<li class="active back-menu"><a href="http://www.painfulwords.com">Go Back</a></li>`? Looks fine, so it's likely something else. Link us to an actual example so we can see.

Comment: Thats exactly the one that does not work. The back menu. It is the only one that should change the page. I tried changing it to index also, and that does not work. Here is an example: http://www.painfulwords.com/purchase.html

Answer (score 1):

The following code in your http://www.painfulwords.com/js/templatemo_script.js JavaScript file is preventing the link from working.

```
$("#menu-list a, #responsive a").on('click',function(e){
  if(this.className == "external") {
    return;
  }

  // THIS BIT HERE cancels the link's default action    
  e.preventDefault();
```

Try giving the link the additional class of `external`.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. Dont even know how you found that but thanks. Didnt even know I had it. I was able to find it but I am far from a programmer. I have little to no programming and HTML experience. So I am not sure what you mean when you say give the link  an additional class.

Comment: @PlattyBear `<a href="http://www.painfulwords.com">Go Back</a>` to `<a href="http://www.painfulwords.com" class="external">Go Back</a>`

Comment: yup I just figured it out as well. Thanks. That did work